# wildcard redirect pages in joomla with.htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, redirect

I have a website where I maked a redirection with .htaccess to redirect my

```
website.com
```

to

```
www.website.com
```

with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.awebsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

that is okey, but I want to redirect all pages, i.e.:

```
website.com/anything
```

(now that page is not redirected) to redirect as well to

```
www.website.com/anything
```

Thanks in advance the help! :)

Comment: Your htaccess is already doing that. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I use the Joomla, the latest version, with SEF urls enabled, but thats not working... if I access website.com/bubble that do not redirect me to www.website.com/bubble

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the OR condition :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.awebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: same thing, doesnt want to redirect... without or

Comment: @Almostokey Clear your browser's cache.

Comment: for testing this I use Private Browsing mode and I tested in another browser this have to work no ?